# What are the alternative ways of making an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, rest

I'm wondering what is the best way to make an AJAX call.

This is what I have right now, and it works just fine.

```
$.ajax({

    url: "/rest/computer",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",

    data: {
        assessmentId: "123",
        classroomId:  "234"
    },

    success: function(objects) {


    // .... code ....


    }
});
```

---

I'm currently seeking another ways of making an Ajax call. 
If there is, should I use my approach ?

Should I move an Ajax call into it own function and call it back ?

Any suggestions on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You could use `$.getJSON()` jquery method

Comment: ... or use just Javascript. But if it is not broke why fix it

Comment: I never asked to review my code. In fact, I mentioned it works fine.

Comment: No matter what you use it's always going through an XMLHTTPRequest object, so I don't think it really matters. It's going to be personal preference.

Comment: What about the `.done()` , what do you guys think about that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

This goes through using an ajax call with and without jQuery. You are going to use one of these methods at some point in your code.

Comment: @开发人员 **BUT** that's the purpose of codereview... You are just on the wrong site

Comment: What does "best" mean to you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there are some other ways  to call ajax

**jQuery**

```
var get_data = function(){
    var result = false;
    $.get('/rest/computer').done(function(awesome_data){
        result = awesome_data;
    });

    return result;
}
```

**$.getJSON**

```
$.getJSON( '/rest/computer', { assessmentId:"123", classroomId:"234"})
  .done( function(resp){
    // handle response here
}).fail(function(){
   alert('Oooops');
});
```

**If you're not using jQuery in your code, this answer is for you**

Your code should be something along the lines of this:

```
function foo() {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', "/rest/computer");
    httpRequest.send();
    return httpRequest.responseText;
}

var result = foo(); // always ends up being 'undefined'
```

Comment: Have you even tried your first example? And are you aware of async model?

Comment: Yes, i have used it some where in my project, but here i have posted is just for sample of alternative ajax call

Comment: Then can you please post a jsFiddle (using their `/echo/` endpoint) and show how a single call to `get_data()` is going to return my result (after an AJAX round-trip)? I'm VERY interested. ((Same goes for your third example--getting information without binding to readstatechange))

Comment: first one simply won't work, you can't return from a function when result is created in asynchronous request. Suggest you read [how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 9):

There is a new async [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) that all of the modern browsers [support](https://caniuse.com/fetch):

```js
fetch('./api/projects', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            title: 'Beispielprojekt',
            url: 'http://www.example.com',
        })
    })
    .then(response => { console.log(response); })
    .catch(error => { console.error(error); });
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976165/8583692) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Not really clear what the underlying context of your question is but for example shown you can use :

```
$.getJSON( url, { assessmentId:"123", classroomId:"234"})
  .done( function(resp){
    // handle response here
}).fail(function(){
   alert('Oooops');
});
```

$.getJSON is a wrapper for `$.ajax` that simplifies needing to add a number of options that are already preset

Answer (score 2):

Following have also one of the type ajax call using post method.

```
var assessmentId = "123"
var formURL = '/rest/computer';
var postData = { "action":"add","data":assessmentId};
$.post(formURL, postData, function( response ) {
    // handle response here 
});
```